# Dictionary to DataTable with variable number of keys C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method like which converts list of Dictionary to DataTable. I also do need to create columns with data type as per data. Some values in dictionary do contain null. I have come up with following:

```
    private static DataTable ToDataTable(List<Dictionary<string, object>> listOfDictionary)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();

        if (listOfDictionary != null && !listOfDictionary.Any())
        {
            return result;
        }

        var maxKeyCount = listOfDictionary.Select(x => x.Keys.Count).Max();

        var maxCountDictionary = listOfDictionary.Where(x => x.Keys.Count == maxKeyCount).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var column in maxCountDictionary.Select(c => new DataColumn(c.Key, c.Value == null ? typeof(string) : c.Value.GetType())))
        {
            result.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        listOfDictionary.ForEach(r => result.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));

        return result;
    }
```

If there are two dictionaries in the list, one dictionary contains three keys and other contain four keys (four being max), then the datatable will have four columns and datarow will have null/empty for the extra column.

this code gives error in this line:

```
    listOfDictionary.ForEach(r => result.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));
```

for trying to add null/empty for extra dictionary keys.

Please suggest.

Comment: The c.Value is giving the error.  So try : c => (c == null)? null : c.Value

Comment: ok lemme try the above

Comment: @jdweng or use the null conditional `c => c?.Value`

Comment: If c is null it will not have a value and give exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
        static DataTable ToDataTable(List<Dictionary<string, object>> dictionaries)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        if (dictionaries != null && dictionaries.Any())
        {
            var columns = GetColumns(dictionaries);
            foreach (var column in columns)
                dataTable.Columns.Add(column);

            var objectArrays = GetObjectArrays(dictionaries, dataTable.Columns);
            foreach (var array in objectArrays)
                dataTable.Rows.Add(array);
        }
        
        return dataTable;
    }

    static List<object[]> GetObjectArrays(List<Dictionary<string, object>> dictionaries, DataColumnCollection columns)
    {
        var arrays = new List<object[]>();
        foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
        {
            var rowValues = new object[columns.Count];
            foreach (var valuePair in dictionary)
                rowValues[columns.IndexOf(valuePair.Key)] = valuePair.Value;
            arrays.Add(rowValues);
        }

        return arrays;
    }

    static List<DataColumn> GetColumns(List<Dictionary<string, object>> dictionaries)
    {
        var columns = new List<DataColumn>();
        var dictWithMostKeys = GetDictionaryWithMostKeys(dictionaries);
        var dataColumns = GetDataColumns(dictWithMostKeys);
        foreach (var column in dataColumns)
            columns.Add(column);

        return columns;
    }


    static IEnumerable<DataColumn> GetDataColumns(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        return dictionary.Select(c => new DataColumn(c.Key, c.Value == null ? typeof(string) : c.Value.GetType()));
    }
    static Dictionary<string, object> GetDictionaryWithMostKeys(List<Dictionary<string, object>> dictionaries)
    {
        var maxKeySum = dictionaries.Select(dictionary => dictionary.Count).Max();
        return dictionaries.First(dictionary => dictionary.Count == maxKeySum);
    }
```